# phonegap run android causing unexpected error on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: cordova

phonegap run android causing unexpected error on ubuntu 12.04.

Please find the error below

phonegap run android

detecting Android SDK environment...

using the local environment

adding the Android platform...

[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 
/home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
at /home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
at _rejected (/home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (/home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/home/arungopan/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)